# How to generate combinations with only the limited given repeated elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

Given the following list:

```
my_list = [-1, 0, 2, 0]
```

How could I get all the triplet combinations?
e.g `[[-1, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], ...]`

I have tried using the `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` functions, but they both fail to do what I want.

```
first = itertools.combinations(my_list, 3)

second = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 3)
```

I set the both variables' second parameter to 3 since I want triplets. However, the `first` variable above (using `itertools.combinations`) does not allow for any repeated elements, so `[-1, 0, 0]`, one of the desired triplets, would not be generated.

Then, the `second` one (using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`) repeats too much. That is, one of the generated elements is `[0, 0, 0]` which should not be generated since there are only two 0s in `my_list`.

Any leads would be much appreciated

Comment: I think `itertools.permutations(my_list, 3)` does what you want.

Comment: `itertools.combindation` is generating `[-1,0,0]`.  if you dont want any duplicate in desired output then you have to filtered out the result values

Comment: But `combinations(my_list, 3)` *does* yield `(-1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny You're right! It worked! How did you know to use permutations instead of combinations? I thought that order did not matter for this, so I was using combinations.

Comment: Use `combinations` if you want `(-1, 0, 0)` but not `(0, -1, 0)` and `(0, 0, -1)`; otherwise, use `permutations`. `permutations`, though, will return things like `(0, 0, -1)` *twice*, as it distinguishes between the two 0s.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Please specify *exactly* what output you want from `[-1, 0, 2, 0]`.

Comment: @chepner The question has already been answered. I can't list all the output hence why I put a few. It isn't necessary to see all the output I want to understand the question.

Comment: Has it been answered? That sounds like the answer does what you want but 1) you didn't accept it and 2) it shows that you'd need to list only one more triple, so "I can't list all" would be wrong. In any case, "question has already been answered" is not a reason to not improve it. Questions/answers are here for future readers as well.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Yes, the question has already been answered. In the previous comments, I told Michael Szczesny to post his correct comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> [`itertools.combinations`] does not allow for any repeated elements

Yeah but the two zeros are separate elements.

Simply testing it shows that `(-1, 0, 0)` *is* there:

```
import itertools

my_list = [-1, 0, 2, 0]

first = itertools.combinations(my_list, 3)
print((-1, 0, 0) in first)

first = itertools.combinations(my_list, 3)
print(*first)
```

Output:

```
True
(-1, 0, 2) (-1, 0, 0) (-1, 2, 0) (0, 2, 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCGzJLWoJD8/p5iLK7cyPiezuETBViFa11BHwUBHwQhIxnJxpWUWgYXhavWS83OTMvMSSzLz84o1oPp0FIw1uQqKMvNKNDSg@g00FTLzFMDaNckwRgui8/9/AA)